# Getting Min and Max Value of a column and other column values

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table with columns of date and time. I need to get the minimum date and its time (col c) and Maximum date and its time( col D) for a unique id.

E.g

```
     A    B                C      D
     1   12/10/2012      8.00     11.00
     1   2/10/2013      10.00    12.00         
     2   1/10/2013      1.00     2.00
     2   9/10/2012      6.00     7.00
```

RESULT

```
     1  12/10/2012   8.00    2/10/2013  12.00
     2  9/10/2012    6.00    1/10/2013   2.00
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
WITH CTE AS 
(
SELECT A, MIN(B) as MinB, MAX(B) as MaxB
FROM TableName
GROUP BY A
)
SELECT C.A, C.MinB, tMin.C as MinC, C.MaxB, tMax.D as MaxD
FROM CTE C
LEFT JOIN TableName tMin on tMin.A = C.A AND tMin.B = c.MinB
LEFT JOIN TableName tMax on tMax.A = C.A AND tMax.B = c.MaxB
```

Comment: Thanks . This works perfectly. Is it possible to get the values without CTE. The reason being I need to join this query with other tables with outer join.

Comment: I don't see why would CTE stop you to join further, but yes you can always replace the word CTE in FROM part with whole subquery from above.

Comment: I would personally wrap the query as another CTE2 and join further on it.