# Select 'date' column with aggregate function

Tags: database, sql-server-2012, aggregate-functions

I am working on Sql Server 2012 below are the sample rows

```
Number         Date
-------------- --------------------
145               2017-04-02 
17345           2017-04-02
16345           2017-04-03
178345         2017-04-03
12745           2017-04-04
16734           2017-04-04
12764          2017-04-05
12367          2017-04-05
```

With this result set I have   requirement that Min, Max and Avg value of column “Number”, with this value I have intention to get the value for date column.

The result set should be   like this:-

```
MinNumber        Date                  
145            2017-04-02
MaxNumber       date
178345         2017-04-03
AVGNumber       date
16345          2017-04-03
```

Then how should I select “date’ with ‘’min (Number)” like this please suggest me solution for expected result set.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17183794/getting-min-and-max-value-of-a-column-and-other-column-values

Answer (score 1):

What about something like:

`SELECT MAX(Number) AS MaxNumber, Date FROM TableName GROUP BY Date LIMIT 1;`

`SELECT MIN(Number) AS MinNumber, Date FROM TableName GROUP BY Date LIMIT 1;`

`SELECT AVG(Number) AS AVGNumber, Date FROM TableName GROUP BY Date LIMIT 1;`